# How to change number of threads used in Homebrew builds?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install Inkscape using Homebrew but the build process takes too long, and it's CPU intensive. So I'd like to pass the number of threads that would be used for the build command. Than way, at least I can use the computer for other tasks while the build process take place.

Comment: Only way I can thinking of going about that off the top of my head would be invoking the [`nice`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)) command on the corresponding `ps`. You may be better off asking this question on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up using:

```
$ HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=1 HOMEBREW_VERBOSE=1 brew install caskformula/caskformula/inkscape
```

`HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS` is the number of threads that wold be used in the build process by `make` and `HOMEBREW_VERBOSE` is set to one to turn on verbose mode for all tasks performed by Homebrew.